# Xml schema having key for different depth

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, key

I have a flexible configuration that uses a `<directory>`-element at different hierarchical levels. Now I would like to ensure that one `directory` can only be used once.

```
<xs:element name="rootElement">

    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            ...
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="xyz" use="required" type="xs:integer"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:key name="key_directory">
        <xs:selector xpath="VARIABLE_DEPTH???/directory"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@path"/>
    </xs:key>

</xs:element>
```

Can this be done like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.//directory` (padding:................ the forum doesn't like short answers ........)